# Why use PhoneGap on Win8 Phone Apps

Tags: javascript, windows-phone-8, cordova

I'm developing with PhoneGap against Android and iOS, which is a big help to access native functions from Javascript. So recently I saw a lot of posts on how to use PhoneGap with Win8 Phone Apps. The question is why would one anyway use PhoneGap for those?

As I understood WinJS/WinRT is kinda a similar Framework which provides access to lower level functions so where is the bigger benefit using Phonegap, besides keeping the same API over different Platforms?

Is there any limitation in WinJS/WinRT, or anything else which only PhoneGap is capable of?

Thx in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choosing Phonegap over WinJS will only make sense when you want the app that you build for ios and/or android to exactly work the same in Windows Phone 8.

But if you're starting from scratch and aren't targeting other platforms, you might as well choose WinJS to build a native app for Windows Phone 8, if you don't mind investing a couple of hours to getting used to WinJS, which i believe is easy for any Javascript developer.

Comment: So in essence besides cross platform just another API. OK THX that was kinda same what i thought about it